# updating a cell value based on another cell value in kendo grid asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, inline-editing

I have been struggling with this problem for two days, any help is hugely appreciated. I have a kendo grid, in which i have given the grid excel like capabilities, i.e on hitting enter the column which is editable is highlighted and I can enter the value and on tab it moves to the next cell. I have a column called external amount which is editable, i.e the user enters the value in the cell and the next column is difference which should be computed whenever the user enters a value in the external amount column and hits on enter.

difference- InternalLocalAmt-ExternallocalAmt. InternalLocalAmt is already populated and isn't editable.

Code snippet:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("OutputCashGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {

        columns.Bound(p => p.InternalLocalAmt).Width(130);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ExternalLocalAmt).Width(130);
  columns.Bound(p => p.LocalDifference).Title("Difference").Width(130).Format("{0:N}").HtmlAttributes(new{id="DifferenceVal"});
 })
  .Sortable()
     .ColumnMenu()
     .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
     .Filterable()
     .Navigatable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(50)
        .ServerOperation(false)
             .Batch(true) // Enable batch updates.
                       .Model(model =>
                            {
                                model.Id(p => p.OutputcashID); // Specify the property which is the unique identifier of the model.
                                //model.Field(p => p.OutputcashID).Editable(false); // Make the ProductID property not editable.
                                model.Field(p => p.OutputcashID).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.Level1).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.TotalRecitems).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.TotalReconcilingItems).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.AsOfDate).Editable(false);
                                model.Field(p => p.InternalLocalAmt).Editable(false);

                            })


           .Update("Editing_Update", "SaveRec")
           )


            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                 .Refresh(true)
                .Input(true)
                .Numeric(false)
             )
                         .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                         .Selectable()
                         .Events(ev => ev.Change("differenceValue"))



        )


<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var gridOutput = $("#OutputCashGrid").data("kendoGrid");

        gridOutput.table.bind("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0 && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey) {

                //get currently navigated cell, this id follows user's navigation
                var activeCell = $("#OutputCashGrid_active_cell");

                //don't do anything if already editing cell        
                if (activeCell.hasClass("k-edit-cell")) return;

                gridOutput.editCell(activeCell);
                var input = activeCell.find("input");



                //number datatype editor loses key press character when entering edit
                if (input.last().attr('data-type') === 'number') {
                   var a= input.val(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode | e.charCode));
                   var selectedItemRow = gridOutput.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                } else {
                    input.val("");
                }
            }
        });


        $("#OutputCashGrid table").on("keydown", "tr", function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (code == 13) { //If key is ENTER
                //find index of the td element
                var activeCell = $("#OutputCashGrid_active_cell");
                var tdIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
                var tdvalue = $(e.target).closest('td').val();
                var cellvalue = activeCell.val();
                var row = $(e).closest("tr");
               // var model = $("#OutputCashGrid").dataItem(row);

                //var difference = selectedItemRow.LocalDifference
                //var TotalInternalAmt = selectedItemRow.InternalLocalAmt
                //var TotalExternalAmt = selectedItemRow.ExternalLocalAmt
                //var updatedDifference = Math.abs(TotalInternalAmt) - Math.abs(TotalExternalAmt)
                //selectedItemRow.set("Differnce", updatedDifference)
                //get the next row's cell
                var nextRow = $(e.target).closest('tr').next();
                var nextRowCell = $(nextRow).find('td:eq(' + tdIndex + ')');



                //focus the next cell on a different context
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var grid = $("#OutputCashGrid").data("kendoGrid");
                    grid.current(nextRowCell);


                }, 0);

            }
        });

</script>
```

[image: In the picture, ExternalLocalAmt is editable, I want the difference to be updated]

I'm attaching a screenshot to show the grid.

Comment: In the picture, I have the external Local Amount that is editable, on hitting enter I want the difference to change. Difference=Internal Local Amount-ExternalLocalAmount

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see you have posted an answer to your question already, but I was struggling with something similar quite recently myself and came up with, what I think, would be a more efficient solution.

Instead of updating all items within your grid dataSource (using your `Calculations` function), you could firstly attach a `change` event to your datasource and then access the items in your row model which have been changed and update as necessary.

For example:

```
var gridOutput = $("#OutputCashGrid").data("kendoGrid");
gridOutput.dataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
   // checks to see if the action is a change and the column being changed is what is expected
   if (e.action === "itemchange" && e.field === "ExternalLocalAmount") {           
       // here you can access model items using e.items[0].modelName;
       e.items[0].Difference = e.items[0].InternalLocalAmount - e.items[0].ExternalLocalAmount;
       // finally, refresh the grid to show the changes
       gridOutput.refresh();
   }
});
```

Comment: That's definitely a better way to implement it. Thank you :). I'm still new to js and kendo, so trying to find my way around.

Comment: No problem happy to help, I guess we all had to be a 'newbie' at one point ;) If this answer or any others have solved your issue/helped you, please don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the solution after much trying, posting the code here in case anybody might need it for future reference

```
function Calculations() {

        var grid = $("#StaggingCashExceptionsGridTest").data("kendoGrid");
        var TotalExternal = 0;

        var gridData = grid.dataSource.view();
        for (var i = 0; i < gridData.length; i++) {

            TotalExternal+=gridData[i].ExternalLocalAmount;//gridDaga[0].ExternalLocalAmount , takes the first row external local amount, till the number of rows in he grid. 
            TotalInternal += gridData[i].InternalLocalAmount;
        difference=TotalExternal-TotalInternal;
 $("#SubDifference").html(difference)//to set the value of difference cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe the following line is preventing the rest from running:

```
var nextRowCell = $(nextRow).find('td:eq(' + tdIndex + ')');
```

Try this instead:

```
var nextRowCell = nextRow.find('td:eq(' + tdIndex + ')');
```

Comment: That just moves to the next row. I want the value of the cell that the user is editing. The edited value. For example - on grid loading, the external local amount is say 200 and the user changes it to 50. I want the value 50

Comment: The var nextRowCell gives me the data of the next row and not the current row that is being edited.

Comment: OK, that's fine, but according to your comments in the code, `changedValues()` isn't being called, so it seemed like maybe it was because of the previous line where it looks like you have an error that is preventing the code from executing subsequent lines.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to call that function on hitting enter, and in that function I wanted to get the value of the updated cell and calculate the difference. But i didn't get anywhere with that logic. So I'm looking for some other logic. I removed that line.

Comment: Oh OK. So just to be clear, you need help with the logic to get the updated value of the External Local Amt and then update the Difference cell?